# Using a value from a get with ngResource in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I'm struggling with using the value that I got from a 'get' in my controller.

This is my code in my controller

```
vm.user;

function onInit(){
   loadUser(vm.queryParams.id[0]);
   console.log(vm.user);
}

function loadUser(UserId) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    User.get({ id: userId }).$promise.then(function (user) {
        vm.user = user;
        defer.resolve();
    });

    return defer.promise;
};
```

When I print the `vm.user` in the `onInit()` it is undefined. While when I look on the view where vm.user is called it just shows me the correct values of the user. So it's not known after the `loadUser()` in the controller but it is in my view.

I would like to first 'get' the user and then use it for further logic in the `onInit()`. How to retrieve the user properly so I can further use it and call its values in the `onInit()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait till the execution of `loadUser()` is finished so as the get the value of user.You can use the promise returned like this and do any calcualtions on it.

```
vm.user;

    function onInit(){
       var promise=loadUser(vm.queryParams.id[0]);
       promise.then(function(response){
       console.log(response);
    });

    }

    function loadUser(UserId) {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        User.get({ id: userId }).$promise.then(function (user) {
            vm.user = user;
            defer.resolve(vm.user);
        });

        return defer.promise;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed my code to match your solution but I still get 'undefined' on the line of the console.log(response); . Maybe something is missing?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Is there any error in console?

Comment: by resolving the vm.user it works indeed. However now I get a Resource object back and I can't get values of that. I tried following code in my onInit()

            vm.user = promise.then(function(response) {
                var resdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log(resdata)
                return resdata;
            });

            console.log(vm.user)


The console.log(resdata) returns an object as I would like it. But the console.log(vm.user) looks like returning the promise Object. How to get it to return the same as console.log(resdata)?

Comment: What is the value inside promise object?

Comment: You can add resdata to a vm instance inside .then and do your calculations there

Comment: If I use following code:
            vm.user = promise.then(function(response) {
                vm.user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log(vm.user)
                return vm.user;
            });
            console.log(vm.user)

Comment: Is this  promise.then(function(response) { vm.user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)); console.log(vm.user) return vm.user; }); console.log(vm.user)  working?

Comment: Actually it seems your answer seems to solve my problem. When I use the global variable in a function that is bound to e.g. a button on my form it does get the value I want. So it solves my problem. 

Though I still actually don't know if there is way to use the value in the onInit() itself outside of the promise.then code. I'll mark your solution as the answer.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Immediately invoke your init function at the beginning of your controller and convert your loadUser function to a service since its a get action. Your service will return the user which you can then set.

(Declare at top of controller):

```
init();

function init(){
        loadUserService.loadUser(UserId)
            .then(function (user) {

                 vm.user = user;
                 defer.resolve();

            })
    }
```